# How do I get character offset information from a pdf document?

Tags: search, pdf

I'm trying to implement search result highlighting for pdfs in a web app. I have the original pdfs, and small png versions that are used in search results. Essentially I'm looking for an api like:

```
pdf_document.find_offsets('somestring')
# => { top: 501, left: 100, bottom: 520, right: 150 }, { ... another box ... }, ...
```

I know it's possible to get this information out of a pdf because Apple's Preview.app implements this.

Need something that runs on Linux and ideally is open source. I'm aware you can do this with acrobat on windows.

Comment: Hi quackingduck,
Were you able to find an answer to this? If yes, please post it here.

Comment: @Thushan `pdftohtml -xml` => `<text top="650" left="72" width="426" height="22" font="6">It also contains`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to look at PdfLib TET
http://www.pdflib.com/products/tet/

(it's not free)

Fabrizio

Answer (score 4):

[CAM::PDF](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CAM-PDF/) can do the geometry part quite nicely, but has some trouble with the string matching sometimes.  The technique would be something like the following lightly-tested code:

```
use CAM::PDF;
my $pdf = CAM::PDF->new('my.pdf') or die $CAM::PDF::errstr;
for my $pagenum (1 .. $pdf->numPages) {
   my $pagetree = $pdf->getPageContentTree($pagenum) or die;
   my @text = $pagetree->traverse('MyRenderer')->getTextBlocks;
   for my $textblock (@text) {
      print "text '$textblock->{str}' at ",
            "($textblock->{left},$textblock->{bottom})\n";
   }
}

package MyRenderer;
use base 'CAM::PDF::GS';

sub new {
   my ($pkg, @args) = @_;
   my $self = $pkg->SUPER::new(@args);
   $self->{refs}->{text} = [];
   return $self;
}
sub getTextBlocks {
   my ($self) = @_;
   return @{$self->{refs}->{text}};
}
sub renderText {
   my ($self, $string, $width) = @_;
   my ($x, $y) = $self->textToDevice(0,0);
   push @{$self->{refs}->{text}}, {
      str => $string,
      left => $x,
      bottom => $y,
      right => $x + $width,
      #top => $y + ???,                                                                                 
   };
   return;
}
```

where the output looks something like this:

```
text 'E' at (52.08,704.16)
text 'm' at (73.62096,704.16)
text 'p' at (113.58936,704.16)
text 'lo' at (140.49648,704.16)
text 'y' at (181.19904,704.16)
text 'e' at (204.43584,704.16)
text 'e' at (230.93808,704.16)
text ' N' at (257.44032,704.16)
text 'a' at (294.6504,704.16)
text 'm' at (320.772,704.16)
text 'e' at (360.7416,704.16)
text 'Employee Name' at (56.4,124.56)
text 'Employee Title' at (56.4,114.24)
text 'Company Name' at (56.4,103.92)
```

As you can see from that output, the string matching will be a little tedious, but the geometry is straightforward (except maybe for the font height).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this using the Adobe Acrobat SDK, a Linux version of which can be [downloaded for free from Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/index.html?navID=downloads). You can use this to [extract text from PDFs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/acrobat_sdk/9/Acrobat9_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=Acrobat9_HTMLHelp&file=DevFAQ_UnderstandingSDK.22.22.html) and then work out offsets. The PDF can then be highlighted by using the [Acrobat XML highlighting file](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdfs/HighlightFileFormat.pdf). This is used to specify which words in which positions are to be highlighted and is fed to acrobat as follows:

http://example.com/a.pdf#xml=http://example.com/highlightfile.xml