# Is there a test suite for PDF files?

Tags: perl, testing, pdf, automated-tests

Is there a test suite for PDFs, preferably in Perl? What I want is some function to test positioning and existence of some text (and if possible a name of a grapic) in a PDF file. Is this theoritically possible with PDF markup?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As jrockway said, there's not a 100% solution available today.  With my [CAM::PDF](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CAM-PDF/) library, you can compute positions for any element in the document.  See my answer to ["How do I get character offset information from a pdf document?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196788/how-do-i-get-character-offset-information-from-a-pdf-document) which shows how to extract coordinates for all text on a page.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is anything pre-built on the CPAN, but Test::Builder and [CAM::PDF](http://search.cpan.org/~cdolan/CAM-PDF-1.52/lib/CAM/PDF.pm#Document_reading) should allow you to write what you want.

Once you get it working, upload it to the CPAN... and then there *will* be a way to test PDFs on the CPAN :)