# How do I gather output from an external command in a Perl script?

Tags: perl, pdf, pdflib

I have a a tool named TET.EXE, product of the PDFlib family, it is used to extract the co-ordinates of a particular text. Using those coordinates in the Perl script we can extract the required text. This is a manual process to run the .EXE and then  give the co-ordinates to Perl, so could any one suggest me to make this entire process hands off.

What I mean is Perl script itself should run the .EXE and get the coordinates required and extract the text.  What are the commands  to be used in linux to run this perl script?
Please, I need your suggestions for the following.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you want perl to launch an executable and do something with the text printed to stdout.... in that case there are a few options:

[Using backticks](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators):

```
my $output = `TED.EXE`;
```

This puts the output of the TED.EXE command in the variable $output, and is most likely sufficient for what you need.

[using IPC::Open3](http://search.cpan.org/~nwclark/perl-5.8.9/lib/IPC/Open3.pm):

```
use IPC::Open3;
my($wtr, $rdr, $err);
my $pid = open3($wtr, $rdr, $err,
                'some cmd and args', 'optarg', ...);
```

This runs your command and associates $wtr, $rdr and $err to the standard input, output and error streams.

There are other ways to do what you want ([Expect.pm](http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect-1.15/Expect.pod), [Run3](http://search.cpan.org/~rschupp/IPC-Run3-0.042/lib/IPC/Run3.pm), etc), but i believe the above mentioned should be sufficient.

Comment: IPC::Open3 is probably overkill, the program spits out the data on STDOUT (not STDERR) and takes the input filename as an argument (so there is no need to mess with STDIN).  A simple open is sufficient and a lot easier to work with.

Answer (score 6):

Perl provides many methods for running an external program and gathering its output.  Based on looking at tet.exe I would say your best bet is to use the [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) function and to loop over the output using a regex to find the coordinates:

```
open my $pdftext, "-|", "/path/to/tet.exe", "--text", $pdffile
    or die "could not open $pdffile using tet.exe: $!";

my ($x, $y);
while (my $line = <$pdftext>) {
    last if ($x, $y) = $line =~ /regex that matches the coords/;
}
die "file did not contain coordinates" unless defined $x;
```

Answer (score 2):

If TET.EXE outputs to the console you can capture that output with

```
my $tetOutput = `tet.exe /myoptions`;
```

If you want to read about it, search for 'perl backtick'

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand question but may be:

```
my $result = qx{TET.EXE some.pdf some params};
```

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider another approach: [use a Perl library to extract the coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196788/how-do-i-get-character-offset-information-from-a-pdf-document).

Answer (score 0):

The [perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html) documentation shows many ways to interact with external processes from Perl.

Many people tell you to use backticks, but you might also check out [IPC::System::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/dist/IPC-System-Simple) which provides more robust ways of doing the same thing by handling operating system specific quirks.